# Sharepoint Platforms List Sync

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, synchronization

Is it possible to sync two SharePoint list that are on different platforms using some sort of Visual Studio? I am new to this and wanted to analyze my options of syncing list across platforms. I would like to be able to add or update items in List 2 if they dont exist in List 1 or delete them if they no longer exist in List1

Ex: List1 is on SharePoint 2013 platform, List2 on Sharepoint 2010 platform

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.SharePoint.Client (CSOM) is a library that can connect remotely to SharePoint environments.  So you could very easily make a connection to one list, gather data, and then open a new context to a second environment and copy that data over.

```
string url = first.site;
string url2 = second.site;
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url))
{
    //GetListItems();
    using (ClientContext context2 = new ClientContext(url2))
    {
         //AddListItems();
    }
}
```

You can do this as an event receiver, scheduled task, whatever.

You can call List.Fields to get a listing of all the fields in an item.  That way you can compare column names between the two lists to figure out what metadata to copy.  Here's a very incomplete example that illustrates the idea.

```
        using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url))
        {
            List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Project Notes Test");
            FieldCollection fields = list.Fields;
            context.Load(fields);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            using (ClientContext target = new ClientContext(url2))
            {
                List list2 = target.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Other List");
                FieldCollection fields2 = list2.Fields;
                target.Load(fields2);
                target.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (Field field in fields)
                {
                   foreach(Field field2 in fields2)
                   {
                       if(field.Title == field2.Title)
                       {
                           listItem1[field.StaticName] = listItem2[field.StaticName];
                       }
                   }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

How do I ensure that the second list is getting the information in the appropriate columns? Do I have to specify every column in the list? ex: collListItem["Title"] = oListItem["Title"]

```js
string url = first.site;
string url2 = second.site;
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(url))
{
    //Retreival code here;
    foreach(ListItem listItem in collListItem)
    {
      using (ClientContext context2 = new ClientContext(url2))
      {
         //Add Items to list;
        
          SP.List rList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("List2");
          ListItemCreationInformation itemCreateInfo = new  ListItemCreationInformation();
          ListItem oListItem = rList.AddItem(itemCreateInfo);
        //******How do I ensure this is getting the code I retrieved in the first list?//
          oListItem["Title"] = "Hello";
          oListItem["Body"] = "New Item";

          oListItem.Update();

          clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could do that, but if you check my answer I have updated it to show how you can compare the columns in one list to another dynamically.  This assumes that list A shares column names and types with List B, if they don't then you are going to have to get very creative to match up the data.